# Write a function that prompts for a file from within a list

Tags: functions, find-file, prompt

As a starting point, this:

```
(defvar myfoo "~/org/test-file-1.org" "myfoo") ; C-x C-e
(defun mybar()
(newline-and-indent)
(insert-file-contents myfoo)) ; C-x C-e
(mybar) ; C-x C-e
Iure repudiandae non alias.
Rerum quia dicta sunt.
Omnis veniam velit nemo saepe in.
```

I'm trying to modify `mybar` such that, instead of using `myfoo`,
the user is presented with a predefined list of files (say those matching `~/org/test-file-*.org`), and is expected to choose the one to be processed. How would I do that?

[image]

UPDATE:

Based on the answer,

```
(setq completions '("~/org/test-file-1.org" "~/org/test-file-2.org")) ; C-x C-e
(defun mybar()
(newline-and-indent)
(insert-file-contents (completing-read "Type something, use TAB for completion: " completions nil t))) ; C-x C-e
(mybar) ; C-x C-e
```

prompts "Type something, use TAB for completion: ". Followed by `TAB`, "Type something, use TAB for completion: ~/org/test-file-", and then `TAB` opens a buffer showing the candidate files:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `completing-read` like this:

```el
(setq completions '("foo" "bar" "baz"))

(completing-read "Type something, use TAB for completion: " completions nil t)
```

The fourth argument being `t` will allow the call to return only if a value from the list is chosen. Read the doc string of the function with `C-h f completing-read` - you can also search the index of the Emacs Lisp Reference manual for it with `C-h i g(elisp) RET i completing TAB RET` (and note that this last command to get the documentation of `completing-read` uses `completing-read` for its implementation - for the record, that's the command `Info-index`).

Comment: I wished I didn't have to press tab twice to get the candidate files to be displayed. Should I post anew to automate that?

Comment: If I press a single TAB at the prompt before typing anything else, I get all the candidates listed. If I've typed something, then a TAB will complete as far as it can (e.g. if I type `b`, it will complete to `ba`) and then a second TAB will show all the candidates that satisfy what's been completed so far. This is standard (and I should say, expected by users) behavior, so I would not do it differently for now. In any case, changing the question thereby invalidating an answer that satisfied whatever conditions you imposed to begin with is frowned upon.

Comment: Changing the question? I need two tabs to get all the candidate listed.

Comment: I described it inaccurately: first TAB gets you the longest common prefix. In my example, there was no  common prefix, so I got the complete list; in your case, there *is* a common prefix, so you get that on first TAB and you need to press a second to get the complete list. Since completion works like that in all cases (at least with the out-of-the-box completion framework that Emacs provides), it is consistent and not a burden, but you may think differently.